# How to make Python function to perform alternately

Tags: python, oop

I wrote a program for simple game (fighting between two fighters). Every fighter has name, 100hp and list of damage points.

Program , for now, runs fine, but I wrote it so that every time one fighter attacks the other ("Goku" attacks "Konan"). Function called `startTheFight` does that.

Goku attacks Konnan...
Goku attacks Konnan...
Goku attacks Konnan...
...and so on

How to make that function to perform alternately, so that I can see who won ("Goku" or"Konan")?
Also, when I call function `upgradeAttack` it does not work, I do not know why
I want to have output like this:

Goku attacks Konnan...
Konnan attacks Goku ...
Goku attacks Konnan...
Konnan attacks Goku ...
...

This is the code:

```
import random

class Fighters:

    attackUp = 0

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name
        self.health = 100
        self.damage = [5, 10, 15, 20]

    def upgradeAttack(self, attUp):
        self.attackUp = self.attackUp + attUp
        print(self.attackUp)
        return self.attackUp

    def startTheFight(self, otherFighter):

        while otherFighter.health > 0:

            AttactDamage = random.choice(self.damage) + self.attackUp
            otherFighter.health = otherFighter.health - AttactDamage

            if otherFighter.health > 0:

                print("{} attacts {}! Health -{}hp | {}'s Health: {}hp\n".format(self.name, otherFighter.name,
                                                                       AttactDamage,otherFighter.name, otherFighter.health))
            else:

                otherFighter.health = 0
                print("{} attacts {}! Health -{}hp | {}'s Health: {}hp\n".format(self.name, otherFighter.name,
                                                                       AttactDamage,otherFighter.name, otherFighter.health))

        else:
            if otherFighter.health <= 0:

                otherFighter.health = 0
                print("{} killed {}! | {}'s Health: {}hp\n{} wins!\n\n".format(self.name, otherFighter.name,
                                                                       otherFighter.name, otherFighter.health, self.name))

    def __str__(self):

        return "Fighters name: {}\nFighters health: {}hp\n".format(self.name, self.health)


Goku = Fighters("Goku")
Konan = Fighters("Konan")

#print(Goku)
#print(Konan)

Goku.startTheFight(Konan)
```

Comment: What would "winning" be?

Comment: It's nice to have class-based questions on here. I'm writing you a suggestion.

Comment: Both players are attacking each other alternately. The player that has 0 health looses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code below in a hacky way. [Working example here](https://repl.it/@NotAnAmbiTurner/WhichHoneydewWebsite). Some notes:

- Your `__str__` method was overly complex and not being used properly (it should practically never `print` directly)
- I suspect (but don't know) this is homework. you are not going to get a good mark on homework if you rely on SO for answers... even what I provided you below isn't what I'd consider "good," but it is "better." If I really want to solve problems, I'll go on HackerRank or something similar, not do other people's homework for them.
- You were missing a logical separation between a "hit" and a "fight," which is mostly what I did
- It was odd / antipattern to me that you were using the first fighter's hit method to hit for both fighters. The benefit of doing it this way (having a `Fighters.hit()` method) is that you can assign different damage arrays to different fighters and in theory the code should still work as expected.
- It's still awkward to me that one fighter instance's `startTheFight` method is being used to create a fight between both (it's not wrong *per se*, but I would personally prefer to have startFight be a class method.
- You should use `f"{var_name}"` if you can (it's only in Python 3.6+) and you should make sure your string methods make sense - it's often easier / more sensible / easier to read to 'build' your final output (string to print, list, dict, etc.), than to have a bunch of random statements giving output throughout the function.
- Finally, did you want the hp to reset to full once a fight is concluded?

Code:

```
import random

class Fighters:

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name
        self.health = 100
        self.damage = [5, 10, 15, 20]

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name

    def hit(attacking_fighter, defending_fighter):

      attack_damage = random.choice(attacking_fighter.damage)
      defending_fighter.health -= attack_damage

      if defending_fighter.health > 0:
        print_str = f"{attacking_fighter} attacks {defending_fighter}!"
      else:
        print_str = f"{attacking_fighter} killed {defending_fighter}! {attacking_fighter} wins the fight!"

      print_str +=  f" Hit for {attack_damage} damage | {defending_fighter}'s Health: {defending_fighter.health}hp"

      print(print_str, end="\n\n")

      return

    def startTheFight(self, otherFighter):

        while otherFighter.health > 0 and self.health > 0:
          self.hit(otherFighter)
          if otherFighter.health <= 0 or self.health <= 0:
            break
          otherFighter.hit(self)

Goku = Fighters("Goku")
Konan = Fighters("Konan")

#print(Goku)
#print(Konan)

Goku.startTheFight(Konan)
```

Example output:

```
Goku attacks Konan! Hit for 10 damage | Konan's Health: 90hp

Konan attacks Goku! Hit for 10 damage | Goku's Health: 90hp

Goku attacks Konan! Hit for 5 damage | Konan's Health: 85hp

Konan attacks Goku! Hit for 10 damage | Goku's Health: 80hp

Goku attacks Konan! Hit for 5 damage | Konan's Health: 80hp

Konan attacks Goku! Hit for 20 damage | Goku's Health: 60hp

Goku attacks Konan! Hit for 10 damage | Konan's Health: 70hp

Konan attacks Goku! Hit for 15 damage | Goku's Health: 45hp

Goku attacks Konan! Hit for 10 damage | Konan's Health: 60hp

Konan attacks Goku! Hit for 20 damage | Goku's Health: 25hp

Goku attacks Konan! Hit for 5 damage | Konan's Health: 55hp

Konan attacks Goku! Hit for 10 damage | Goku's Health: 15hp

Goku attacks Konan! Hit for 10 damage | Konan's Health: 45hp

Konan killed Goku! Konan wins the fight! Hit for 15 damage | Goku's Health: 0hp
```

Comment: This is good, but its kinda confusing for me because you used two methods. I wanted to have one method that will do all the job. This part is not so clear: `self.hit(otherFighter)`. Also I wanted to have the output of 0hp when some fighter is killed. 

I have idea to put my function in one `for loop`, and to set counter for i, and then to set that the Goku attacks when the i is odd number and Konan attacks when i is even number, but I couldnt manage to get the result that I want.
And no, this isn't my homework, I'm learning Python by giving myself some tasks and problems.

Comment: Okay, well one thing you should be aware of is that it's better style to separate functions into the smallest discrete components. Having a huge function that does everything is generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: Oh, ok, i didnt know that!

Anyways ... THANKS A LOT !

Comment: One more question: What if I want to write a method so that when I call it, it 
 increases the attack damage for 1 (`self.damage = [6, 11, 16, 21]`)
How should that function look?
I have tried to make it but the attack damage stays the same.
Check out the code, I updated it

Comment: You don't need a whole function for that. After you calculate the damage with `random`, just add `+1`. If you want to make it a function, just pass in the damage you got from the list, add one, return that value.

Comment: @Can you check the code that i have posted,I want to make a function that will update/override the previous list of damage. I have tried to do that but It does not work

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem with the 
upgradeAttack function is that you&#39;re creating a new property of the Fighter instance. What you want is probably something like this (I&#39;m on my  phone so take this with a grain of salt) `self.damage = [x + attUp for x in self.damage]`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of further suggestions: it makes no sense for a class that models a fighter to be called `Fighters`. It should be singular, `Fighter`. Fighters don't have a name, one fighter has a name. While it is conceivable for one fighter to start the fight, it is odd that one fighter directs it; I would rather have either a static method (`Fighter.fight(goku, conan)`) or have a distinct class, `Fight`, that represents an instance of the event where two people battle. It would also be in charge of reporting the fight. It is also not very nice for an instance to do changes to another instance; Conan can hit, but only Goku should have governance over his health. The `while` loop is more complex than it needs to be; the structure of the fight is that the attacker hits the defender, then *they switch places*. This makes the flow control much, much easier. Finally, by Python naming conventions, instance variables should be lowercase; people could be tricked into thinking `Goku` and `Conan` are class names. (This is just one example, there are other case issues.) So with this in mind, a bit of a rewrite of a rewrite:

```
import random

class Fighter:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100
        self.damage = [5, 10, 15, 20]
        self.strength = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def hit(self, defender):
        attack_damage = random.choice(self.damage) + self.strength
        defender.suffer(attack_damage)
        return attack_damage

    def suffer(self, attack_damage):
        self.health -= attack_damage

    def is_dead(self):
        return self.health <= 0

    def fight(self, other):
        return Fight(self, other)

class Fight:
    def __init__(self, attacker, defender):
        self.attacker = attacker
        self.defender = defender

    def round(self):
        damage = self.attacker.hit(self.defender)

        if self.defender.is_dead():
            print_str = f"{self.attacker} killed {self.defender}! {self.attacker} wins the fight!"
        else:
            print_str = f"{self.attacker} attacks {self.defender}!"
        print_str += f" Hit for {damage} damage | {self.defender}'s Health: {self.defender.health}hp"
        print(print_str, end="\n\n")

        self.attacker, self.defender = self.defender, self.attacker

    def run(self):
        while not self.attacker.is_dead():
            self.round()

goku = Fighter("Goku")
konan = Fighter("Konan")
goku.strength = 3

goku.fight(konan).run()
```

From here, an advanced exercise would be to turn the fight into a generator so you can run it round by round more easily, for example.